# error: no match for ‘operator[]’ (operand types are ‘std::map<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, int>’ and ‘char’)

Tags: c++, algorithm, c++11, stdmap, stdstring

I wanted to test if the increment `++` works for the `std::map` :

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>

using namespace std;
int main() 
{
   map<string, int> map;;
   map['1'] = 0;
   map['1']++;
   cout << map['1'] << endl;
   return 0;
}
```

And Ì get the error of the title for :

```
map['1'] = 0;
```

I do not understand why

Comment: "1" is a string literal, '1' is char.

Comment: Beware that you have a double semicolon `map<string,int> map;;`

Comment: All you needed just read the error message till the end.

Comment: Thank you @sebastian, and S.M I didn't know that ' =/= "

Comment: Please get [some good books](https://stackoverflow.com/a/388282/440558) or take some clases to learn C++ properly. Don't use competition sites as a learning resources (except as a show-case of bad code and bad habits).

Comment: ... and while you're at it, this is also a good thing to read: [Why should I not `#include <bits/stdc++.h>`?](https://stackoverflow.com/Questions/31816095/Why-Should-I-Not-Include-Bits-Stdc-H.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In C++ `'1'` is a character, not a string literal, and your map has a key `std::string`, which is not same types. That is why the `std::map::operator[]` gave you the compiler error, it is mismatch type.

You need `""` for mentioning it is a string literal.

```
map["1"] = 0;
```

---

Also, have a read:

- [Why is "using namespace std;" considered bad practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice)
- [Why should I not #include <bits/stdc++.h>?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31816095/why-should-i-not-include-bits-stdc-h)

Comment: Technically, `"1"` is not a `std::string` either, and yet `map["1"]` works, because a `std::string` can be *constructed* from a string literal, but it can't be constructed from a single `char`, at least not with the code attempted.